# Domain specific URL Prefix while sharing SharePoint content

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, cross-domain, tenant

there are 3 different domains added in one O365 tenant. But the SharePoint and Onedrive URL is being created with the first registered domain.

it there any provision that we can create different SharePoint site with different URL prefix.
i.e.
company1.sharepoint.com
company2.sharepoint.com
company3.sharepoint.com

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can only have one SharePoint URL per tenant (technically when using multi-geo, each geo will have it's own specific URL assigned to that site collection, but that isn't what you're wanting to achieve).

Comment: you mean to say, if I set three different site collection in different geo, and assign separate primary domain to each geo, then I will be getting three different URL prefix ?

Comment: Yes, however they will all respond to the default prefix, too. And it requires a minimum license count of 250. Users must be assigned a license when their default geo is not your home geo. This will also move their EXO mailboxes automatically, and you can manually move their OneDrive and SPO sites as needed.

This isn't really the solution your after -- Microsoft doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

The domain you created is an onmicrosoft.com fallback domain in the Microsoft 365.
It serves as a default email routing address for your Microsoft 365 environment.

A SharePoint tenant can only have one Top-level SharePoint site. You cannot create sites using another domain.

Reference ：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-or-replace-your-onmicrosoftcom-domain?view=o365-worldwide

[image]